# Appropriate fit function for $\phi$ meson mass from $K^{+}K^{-}$ pair

Tags: particle-physics, statistics, models

I am attempting to measure the mass of the $\phi$ meson using the decay mode $\phi \to K^{+}K^{-}$. I have isolated the $\phi$ meson candidates using this decay mode, and have constructed the graph below, but am finding it hard to find an appropriate fit function to determine the mass of the $\phi$ meson.

[image: Phi candidate mass distributions]

The data is from the CDF detector, and so the peak will be Gaussian shaped (no need to perform a convolution of a Breit-Wigner distribution with a Gaussian distribution as resolution is too low to see the effects of a Breit-Wigner distribution over a Dirac delta distribution).

I have tried the following fit function but without luck:

$$\text{fit}(M, p_{1},p_{2},p_{3},p_{4},\mu,\sigma) = p_{1}\sqrt{p_{2} + p_{3} M} + p_{4} \phi(\frac{M-\mu}{\sigma})$$

Where $\phi$ is the standard normal distribution PDF.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I should use to model a $\phi$ resonance on top of combinatorial background?

Comment: Are these prompt $\phi$ mesons or do they come from a particular decay?

Comment: They are from the decay mode $B_{s}^{0} \to J/\psi + \phi$, does that help?